# tyring to prove product rule for higher-order partial derivatives

Tags: calculus

> Prove that
>
> $$ \partial^{\alpha} (fg) = \sum_{\beta + \gamma = \alpha} \frac{
>  \alpha!}{\beta! \gamma!} (\partial^{\beta}f)(\partial^{\gamma} g) $$

Here we are using multi index notation $\alpha = (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ and $\partial^{\alpha}(fg) = \dfrac{ \partial (fg)^{\alpha_1+...+\alpha_n} }{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1} ... \partial x_n^{\alpha_n} } $

I think we can use induction and we start with $n=1$ that is when we have a function of a single variable. So, we have $\alpha = \alpha_1$ and we have the usual leibniz rule:

$$ \partial^{\alpha_1} (fg) = \frac{ \partial (fg)^{\alpha_1} }{\partial x_1 ^{\alpha_1} } = \sum_{i=1}^{\alpha_1} \frac{\alpha_1!}{i! (\alpha_1-i)!} (\partial^if)(\partial^{\alpha_1-i}g) = \sum_{\beta + \gamma = \alpha} \frac{
 \alpha!}{\beta! \gamma!} (\partial^{\beta}f)(\partial^{\gamma} g) $$

where $\beta = i$ and $\gamma = \alpha_1-i$ and $\alpha = \alpha_1$. So it holds for this case. Is this a correct approach to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd prove this by induction. But not induction on $n$; it looks to me like induction on $|\alpha|=\alpha_1`+\dots+\alpha_n$.